# LogNet gRPC Spring Boot starter - resolve service without service discovery

Tags: java, spring-boot, grpc-java

I am trying to set up Spring Boot microservices which will communicate via gRPC. I am using the LogNet (https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter) Spring Boot starter and am trying to figure out how to have a client/consumer service "connect" to a server/producer service **without** using service discovery (e.g. Eureka).

I have not been able to find information on how to configure the producer to listen to a port that I specify.

I would then attempt to connect to it from the consumer with code like the following:

```
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("127.0.0.1", 9110).usePlaintext()
    .keepAliveWithoutCalls(true).build();
greeterStub = GreeterGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
```

Obviously, the host and port would be configurable unlike in the snippet above.

Comment: `producer` is your server or client?

Comment: Producer is the "server".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *producer* you mean a gRPC server, then you can configure its port in your `application.yml/properties`:

```
grpc:
    port: 6565
```